# XCode edit UITableView textFields for different rows

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uitableview

I have a program that displays a table with just 1 Cell row with the customer's information to be keyed in using 2 textFields. (Shown below)

[image: First screenshot]

The user is able to click on the Addition sign to add a new row to their interests.

When the user selects the Main Category, the Sub Category should be auto filled with information.

My problem is, when i have say 2 rows of cells, I'm unable to auto populate the second subCategory with the selection from the mainCategory because I have no idea how to identify them.

I've implemented both the UITableView/UIPickerView delegates in this view.

Comment: as u will be getting indexPath from the textField tags, using that get the whole cell, from cell u can do what ever u want right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the convenient `tag` attribute of the text fields. You can set these in Interface Builder inside Xcode to distinguish between your two fields.

Now you can identify the particular row and its index path like this, say, in `textField:didBeginEditing`:

```
#define mainTag 2
#define subTag 3

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)textField.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
UITextField *mainCategory = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:mainTag];
UITextField *subCategory = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:subTag];
```

The trick is that the text field is a subview of a view called `contentView` which is part of every `UITableViewCell`, which again is a subview of the cell itself.

Comment: Important note: `[_tableView indexPathForCell:cell]` return nil if cell is out of the visible area.

Comment: That would be unlikely if the text field in the cell is being edited. One could set the table view to non-scrolling to prevent this.